# Efficient Bitmap memory use in Android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, imageview, scaling

This is a general question about the way in which Android manages Bitmaps. I am wondering if it is better from a memory perspective to provide correctly sized Bitmaps to ImageViews rather than incorrectly sized Bitmaps that Android has to scale. For a working example if we assume an ImageView 1000 x 1000 and I set a Bitmap that is 1024 x 1024 (FitCentre) Android will have to scale the image. Does it then have to hold on to both the original image and the scaled version, more or less doubling memory usage? If in the alternate scenario I present a 1000 x 1000 Bitmap to the 1000 x 1000 ImageView, is only one image held? Just a question so I know the most efficient way to handle Bitmaps, particularly large images.

Answer (score 0):

The Android will scale your image, but this will happen after your image has loaded in memory, and it won't prevent the notorious **OutofMemoryError** exception from happening.

The solution would be to scale the image before loading it in memory, and then use it.

The Android documentation explains in details how to mitagate this issue, and in general how to display Bitmaps efficiently: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thank for the reply but I don't believe it quite answers my question. I am trying to understand if I set an image that is NOT the View size does the system have to carry the image I provide and also a scaled version or is the scaling done directly to Canvas?